# Android app crashes in-spite of Try/Catch

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to write an app while working with Network Service Discovery(NSD) and i notice that whenever it crashes, the line of error comes from a block of code inside a try/catch.I can't specify a catch for SocketException because i believe (because I tried) that IOException covers that too. How do I proceed?

Here is the code

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
                setLocalPort(mServerSocket.getLocalPort());

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ServerSocket Created, awaiting connection");
                    setSocket(mServerSocket.accept()); //line of error
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected.");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (mChatClient == null) {
                        int port = mSocket.getPort();
                        InetAddress address = mSocket.getInetAddress();
                        connectToServer(address, port);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error creating ServerSocket: ", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the full error log

```
06-02 06:07:43.804 26779-26779/com.example.android.nsdchat E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
06-02 06:07:43.829 26779-26786/com.example.android.nsdchat E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-02 06:07:45.117 26779-26794/com.example.android.nsdchat E/ONS: 1. NsdChat (_http._tcp. -- 0 -- 0)
06-02 06:07:47.132 26779-26796/com.example.android.nsdchat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f9de01110
06-02 06:07:56.925 26779-26779/com.example.android.nsdchat E/IAE: listener in use
06-02 06:07:59.331 26779-26779/com.example.android.nsdchat E/IAE: listener in use
06-02 06:08:04.004 26779-26794/com.example.android.nsdchat E/NsdHelper: Resolve Succeeded. name: NsdChat, type: ._http._tcp, host: /192.168.82.103, port: 48308
06-02 06:08:05.995 26779-26796/com.example.android.nsdchat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f9da665c0
06-02 06:08:07.364 26779-26796/com.example.android.nsdchat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f9da6c990
06-02 06:08:07.716 26779-26793/com.example.android.nsdchat E/ChatConnection: Error creating ServerSocket: 
                                                                         java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
                                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
                                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:63)
                                                                             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:94)
                                                                             at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:217)
                                                                             at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:141)
                                                                             at com.example.android.nsdchat.ChatConnection$ChatServer$ServerThread.run(ChatConnection.java:153)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-02 06:08:07.997 26779-26796/com.example.android.nsdchat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f9dcd2bd0
```

Comment: If your question is how to catch SocketException differently than IOException, I believe that java goes down the line of catches. This means that if you catch the more specific SocketException first, and then IOException in a different catch block, you can handle them in different ways.

Comment: Your app does not crash because of the SocketException - you are catching it and logging the error, and your app will proceed after that. There's something else that is causing the crash. If your log is too cluttered, try commenting out the `e.printStackTrace()` temporarily to find out what is actually causing the crash.

Comment: couldn't add it to comment so i edited the question with full error log. not much different from the snippet

Comment: What I'm saying is that the SocketException that is being thrown does not cause your application to crash. You catch the exception, and your app proceeds after that. If your app crashes, it must be something else that is causing it. It might be easier to spot the actual error that crashes your app if you temporarily remove the `e.printStackTrace()` line from the catch clause.

Comment: It's more over that once the exception is catched he is outside of the loop which will cause the thread to close. It's an runnable class and the error happens inside the run method which means his catch is the end of the run method. Once it is finished it will just stop and if no other activity etc is handling all that it crashes.

Comment: @Nico Please could you break down your comment for me. Are you saying the error is in the try/catch block or is caused because i'm using a runnable class?

Comment: Well when you make a class runnable this typically means you will always call this class with a new thread. The run method is what will keep the class alive. Your run method however is always finished once an exception get's thrown. Meaning a class that does nothing will be gc'ed and is not existent anymore. So my guess is that, where you start the thread you rely on it running correctly and when it doesn't and/or dissapears you don't handle it correctly.

Comment: Oh I just realized you are working with a ServerSocket. Please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) When you use `mServerSocket.accept()` you are calling a blocking method. `accept()` will wait as long as it needs ( if no timeout is specified ) until someone wants to connect to him. This might be a problem with your businesslogic.

Comment: Hi @Nico I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()) in the documentation `Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException` but upon multiple runs i have determined that the Thread state is `RUNNABLE`. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Fixed it! Turns out the line of error `setSocket(mServerSocket.accept());` needed to close a socket that was null at that point. Thabks guys. How do i mark the question answered without an actual answer?

Comment: @kbluue you don't - post the answer yourself and mark it as accepted instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Turns out the line of error setSocket(mServerSocket.accept()); needed to close a socket that was null at that point.

Comment: The main question is: why it crashes when the code is inside try catch block!